# At what point should one recite Bracha asher yatzar

Tags: halacha, blessing, netilat-yadayim-washing, bathroom, ruach-rah

Having washed one's hands after excusing oneself, Does one say the *bracha* ***asher yatzar*** after drying our hands or before? Some guy taught that we're to say the bracha before drying the hands.

I checked many halacha books including the makor chaim by Rabbi K D HaLevi and Kitzur Shulchan Aruch by Rabbi S.  Gandzfried, and all says,  One needs to say asher yatzar after Washroom. No one talks about drying.

Can someone please clarify?

Comment: There is no rational for this. The only rational is for birkat Al netilat : before making netilat and drying is a part of this making

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Shulchan Aruch 4,18](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.4.18?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) says one must wash ones hand after going to the toilet, the Mishna Brura seif 40 explains that even if one merely enters the toilet he must wash his hands because of the רוח רעה the metaphysical contamination of his hands and the Kaf Hachaim adds ideally one should wash 3 times each hand after going to the toilet as this *Ruach Raah* is like the *ruach raah* that comes when one wakes up from ones sleep.

The Beer Heitev 4,1 says one can make the Bracha after washing ones hands before drying them:

> כתב בסדר היום ד**מיד אחר הנטילה יברך ולא ימתין על הניגוב** וכ''כ ברכת אברהם ח''ג

The Shaarei Teshuva in 4,1 however brings Rabbis that argue to wait to make a *Bracha* till one dries ones hands after washing them to get rid of the *Ruach raah* ritual contamination:

> עבה"ט במחזיק ברכה בשם אור צדיקים למהר"מ פאפרש שכתב בשם מהר"מ ניגרין שאין רוח רעה סרה מהידים שחרית עד אחר הניגוב ולפ"ז **לא יברך עד שינגב** דלא כמ"ש בשם סדה"י הכנה"ג (הביאו המג"א כמ"ש הבה"ט)

In conclusion ideally one should either dry ones hands after washing them, or wash ones hands 4 times (this suggestion is given by the Kaf Hachaim to remove the *Ruach Raah* completely) then make a Bracha Asher Yatzar.

Answer (score 0):

The [Eshel Avraham (OC 6) writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Eshel_Avraham_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.6.1?lang=bi):

> אשר יצר. אבל לא על נט"י דא"צ לנטילה ודי בנקיון עפר וצרורות
>
> [Upon exiting the bathroom one says] Asher Yatzar - But not Al Netilas Yadayim, as washing is not needed; cleaning with dirt and stones is sufficient.

We see that the benchmark for making an Asher Yatzar is just that one’s hands are clean. As such, one may make the Beracha before drying his hands.

Comment: Which Eshel Avraham? [Butchach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_David_ben_Asher_Anshel_Buchach) or [Peri Megadim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_ben_Meir_Teomim)?

Comment: @DoubleAA Whichever one is on Sefaria; I’ve included the link. I didn’t realize there were two, but I presume it’s Butchach, since it’s certainly not Pri Megadim.